# Some modifications to the appendices appearance

Tags: appendices, appendix

Consider the following mwe:

```
% Packages and bibliography
\documentclass[english,a4paper,9pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[titletoc,title,page]{appendix} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\tableofcontents  

\chapter{Introduction}  \setcounter{page}{1}   
\pagenumbering{arabic}

Hey

\begin{appendices}

\appendix

\chapter{Hey}
\label{chap:hey}
Appendix content.


\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the word "Appendix" to appear before the chapter name. Right now, I get "A. Hey", but I would like to have "Appendix A. Hey".

How could I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use the `book` class instead of `scrbook` you get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \mbox{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
}
\makeatother
```

before `\chapter{Hey}`.